# Are Objects inside of other objects being saved to the database?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jpa, mariadb

I hope someone understands, what I mean by this question. I try to explain it as good as possible: 
I want to save an object, which is a JPA-entity to the database, by using
`accountRepository.save(account);` 
Are other objects (member & house), being present in List<> on the account entity (Due to a M:1 relationship), saved too, or is it just the attributes being saved, with me manually having to write  `houseRepository.save(house);` and then getting this specific house and adding it to the account entity that way?

Comment: That depends on how you specified the cascade rules of the relationship.

Comment: it depends on how your model is bound to the db

Comment: That is something you can decide yourself by choosing the [CascadeType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) of your Entity relations. (Default is No cascading afaik)

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS I am using "CascadeType.ALL" in all of my OneToMany relationships.

Comment: @fantaghirocco What do you mean by "How your model is bound to the database"?